# @font-face' weight - aliases

Tags: html, css, font-face

I need to use a external font for a website. On sepcify the `@font-face` i like to use the alias instead of the Number-representation. Therefore `bold` is an alias for 700. `normal` is the alias for 400.

My questions:

1. What is the numerical representation of alias `lighter`?
2. What are the HTML-Tags that naturallly use different alias than `normal`/`inherited`? (i only know the `<b>`-tag  and the `<h*>`-tag that uses the `bold` alias)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The value resulting from computing `bolder` and `lighter` varies based on the value that is inherited from the element's parent, so there is no singular numeric representation of either keyword. See the section on the [`font-weight` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop).

   Because `bolder` and `lighter` are special values, it is not necessary to declare them in a `@font-face` rule. The spec says this under the [font property descriptors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop-desc) (which include the `font-weight` descriptor, not to be confused with the `font-weight` CSS property):

   > The values for these descriptors are the same as those for the corresponding font properties except that relative keywords are not allowed, ‘bolder’ and ‘lighter’.
2. This depends on the browser default styles, but [section 10 of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html) has some guidelines that most browsers follow. Notably, the `b` and `strong` elements actually use `bolder`, not `bold`.

   The elements listed with different weights  in the HTML5 default stylesheet guidelines are

   ```
   b, strong { font-weight: bolder; }
   ```

   from [section 10.3.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#phrasing-content-0), followed by

   ```
   h1 { margin-top: 0.67em; margin-bottom: 0.67em; font-size: 2.00em; font-weight: bold; }
   h2 { margin-top: 0.83em; margin-bottom: 0.83em; font-size: 1.50em; font-weight: bold; }
   h3 { margin-top: 1.00em; margin-bottom: 1.00em; font-size: 1.17em; font-weight: bold; }
   h4 { margin-top: 1.33em; margin-bottom: 1.33em; font-size: 1.00em; font-weight: bold; }
   h5 { margin-top: 1.67em; margin-bottom: 1.67em; font-size: 0.83em; font-weight: bold; }
   h6 { margin-top: 2.33em; margin-bottom: 2.33em; font-size: 0.67em; font-weight: bold; }
   ```

   from [section 10.3.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#sections-and-headings), and

   ```
   th { font-weight: bold; }
   ```

   from [section 10.3.9](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#tables).

Comment: So `<b>` uses bolder `bolder` but noone uses `lighter`?

Comment: @Peter Rader: Not that I know of. There never really was a need for pages using default stylesheets or sites that pre-dated modern CSS to have lighter text in the middle of bold text anywhere.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, webkit browsers use `bold` for `<b>` while IE and Mozilla use `bolder`. This may depend on the implementation though; I should do some testing.

Comment: @MrLister May this why a `reset.css` shall be used?

Comment: @PeterRader Sure, if you want to remove differences like that. Most reset stylesheets however, are overkill; they remove too many styles and don't take the user's preferences into account.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the numerical representation of alias `lighter`?

Font-weight Values:

- **normal**
     Normal font weight. Same as 400.
- **bold**
     Bold font weight. Same as 700.
- **lighter**
     One font weight lighter than the parent element (among the available weights of the font).
- **bolder**
     One font weight darker than the parent element (among the available weights of the font).
- **100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900**
     Numeric font weights for fonts that provide more than just normal and bold. If the exact weight given is unavailable, then 600-900 use
  the closest available darker weight (or, if there is none, the
  closest available lighter weight), **and 100-500 use the closest
  available lighter weight** (or, if there is none, the closest
  available darker weight). This means that for fonts that provide only
  normal and bold, 100-500 are normal, and 600-900 are bold.

Comment: One font weight is 1? So one font weight of noramal is 401?

Comment: font weights are on a scale of 100-900(technically 1000) in increments of 100.

Comment: @peterrader No. `Normal` is 400, not 401. I didn't mean to add up.